# No water in laundry

Tags: plumbing, laundry

A washing machine repair person came yesterday and since then I do not seem to have water in the laundry room. Trying to contact the company but no luck so far. What I see under the laundry sink are three taps - two connected to the washing machine and one on the left (see picture). Since I have no water in the sink or washing machine I'm assuming the tap on the left is the main tap for the laundry room that I should be working with, but turning it does not seem to do anything. What else should I check?[image]

Comment: the handle on the shutoffs has to be parallel to the pipe - yours are perpendicular.

Comment: What are those shut off valves attached to? Is that the back of the washing machine, the wall?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Judging by the position of the handles, they are simply turned off.

Comment: Those handles do not move at all :-( I also do not have water on the faucet above the laundry sink which is not connected to those two pipes.

Comment: @NinaN where does the pair of braided hoses go when they disappear off the top of your pic? I bet they go to the sink. And those 2 handled do move - you might just need more leverage.

Comment: Sometimes there is a local shutoff valve between the main water supply line and the branch line that provides services water to another location. If you have a basement, you can trace the main water supply line and the line that serves the laundry area, a valve may be there that was not turned back on after the repair.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your replies - it was those taps and handles were too stiff for me to turn. The company did send someone else and he fixed it in 5 seconds. I guess I should go to a gym so I'll be able to turn those handles myself in the future ...